# Setting @null for textColor dynamically in android

Tags: android, null, textview, android-edittext, textcolor

I need an EditText to appear as a TextView for a form that will change from being write to read only.  I have found a useful snippet of code to do this in a layout:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/title"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          style="?android:attr/textViewStyle"
          android:background="@null"
          android:textColor="@null" />
```

I need to do this dynamically (not in the layout).  I know that the background can be set to `@null` by using `setBackgroundResource(null)`.  Because `setTextColor(int color)` takes an `int`, I assume that a specific color must be selected.  What is the correct color to choose that would be the equivalent to `@null`?  A color from the default theme?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you get if you use `getTextColors()` with one that is set to `@null` in XML? That should tell you what colors are used for each state when it's null.

Comment: When I call `getTextColors().getDefaultColor()` it returns -4276546 (`#FFBEBEBE`) which is a light gray.  If I do not set `textColor` at all, I get -16777216 (`#FF000000`) black.  This further tells me that a default theme color is being used and that `@null` does not mean transparent or black.

Answer (score 0):

You can create  color in your string.xml like

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Then you can assign it to like

```
txtTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
```

`#00000000` is equal to null.

Comment: Thanks, but this sets to color to 0 (same as `Color.TRANSPARENT`).  This makes the text invisible.  I don't think `@null` has the same affect on the text color as a transparent value.

Comment: but your question is `Setting @null for textColor dynamically in android. @null=#00000000.

Comment: As tested and shown in the comments above, `@null` does not equal `#00000000`

Answer (score 0):

You can call these methods on any `View` to disable editing or clicking. It will effectively make the view read only. Set them to `true` to re-enable them.

```
view.setFocusable(false);
view.setClickable(false);
view.setLongClickable(false);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am already doing this.  My intent for this question is to make the `EditText` appear uneditable to the user (ie not look like an `EditText`, but more like a `TextView`.)

Comment: You could swap the `EditText` with a `TextView` at the same time you make it read only.

Comment: Yes, I considered this.  I think I will just hard code a color value into the final result.  The rest of it works great removing the background, just couldn't nail down the color.  I did find the `#FFBEBEBE` color in the sdk as a "secondary text color" or something like that.